# C language ~ data file by using delete function modify text file content (File IO)

Tags: c, file, file-io, text-files

I'm the novice and still learning  C language. Currently, I'm having a problem with my code. The task is delete something in the file IO, by default there is some record in my txt file. The task is asking the user to input the which lines he/she would like to delete in txt file. However, the problem occurs:

1 )the c program still work in the first time, but the second, third time and below cannot work.(that mean just can delete lines in the first time)

I think it is a buffer problem, so I add many fflush codes, but still cant solve.

2) I would like to change my program into using a keyword to find the record and delete.User type the recordnum can delete whole item record. However, I have not idea how it works.

if someone can help me , I am very grateful and happy.
 1)code is below :

```
#include<stdio.h> #include<stdlib.h>      
int main(){
FILE *fileptr1, *fileptr2, *fileptr3;
char filename[40]="itemrecord.txt";
char save;
int delete_line, temp = 1;
char reply;

printf("Enter file name: ");
scanf("%s", filename);

do{


//open file in read mode
fileptr1 = fopen(filename, "r");
if (fileptr1== NULL){
printf("open unsuccessful,file not exist"); 
exit(1);
}
save = getc(fileptr1);
while (save != EOF)
{
    printf("%c", save);
    save = getc(fileptr1);
}

//rewind
rewind(fileptr1);

fflush(stdout);
printf(" \n\n Enter line number of the line to be deleted <type 0 = not 
delete anything>:");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%d", &delete_line);


//open new file in write mode
fileptr2 = fopen("copy.c", "w");
save = 'a';
while (save != EOF)
{
    save = getc(fileptr1);
    //except the line to be deleted
    if (temp != delete_line)
    {
        //copy all lines in file replica.c
        putc(save, fileptr2);
    }
    if (save == '\n')
    {
        temp++;
    }
   }

fclose(fileptr1);
fclose(fileptr2);
remove(filename);
//rename the file replica.c to original name
rename("copy.c", filename);
fflush(stdout);
printf("\nThe contents of file after being changed are as follows:\n");

fileptr1 = fopen(filename, "r");
save = getc(fileptr1);
while (save != EOF)
{
    printf("%c", save);
    save = getc(fileptr1);
}
fflush(stdout);
fflush(stdin);
fclose(fileptr1); 

 printf("\n\n Delete anther item?<y/n>: ");
 scanf("%c",&reply);  

 }while(reply=='y' || reply=='Y');
  return 0;
  }
```

**Result :**

```
Enter file name:itemrecord
mary 1 123
sam  2 124
bob  3 125

Enter line number of the line to be deleted<type 0=not delete anything>:1

The contents of file after being changed are as follows:
sam  2 124
bob  3 125

Delete other record?<y/n>:y
sam  2 124
bob  3 125

Enter line number of the line to be deleted<type 0=not delete anything>:1

The contents of file after being changed are as follows:
sam  2 124
bob  3 125   

Delete other record?<y/n>:n

//second time doesn't work.//
```

I'm sorry for the long code and long question, but I'm so confusing...

2)if my record into

```
Mary
1
123

sam  
2 
124

bob  
3 
125
```

SO how I can type 'Mary' delele whole record item? something like that...

```
sam  
2 
124

bob  
3 
125
```

Comment: Note that [`getc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an *`int`*. That's actually kind of important for the `EOF` check.

Comment: Also, calling `fflush` with an input-only stream (like `stdin`) is explicitly mentioned in the C specification as *undefined behavior*. Some compilers implement it as an *extension* of the library, but you should never really do that.

Comment: You never reset `temp`. (Which is poorly named, btw).

Comment: thanks  a lot!! I  reset the temp and solve my first question

Comment: So i should truncate the file to slove my second question? (because I'm the novice and sorry for my stupid brain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
int delete_line, temp;
char reply;

printf("Enter file name: ");
scanf("%s", filename);

do{
    temp = 1;
    ....
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I would like to know the concept and how it work , because it is not similar with delete_line function. if delete the record item(Mary record) line-by-line is not userfriendly.  grateful for your reply:)

Comment: The problem with your code is that 'temp' needs re-initialised to '1' (temp = 1;) at the top of the do loop - as shown in the snippet of code above.

Comment: yup, it is helpful and I solved.  but I'm still confusing about how to delete designation entire record (like my question second part mentioned that